# Valid query to check if row exists in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

Is this the most efficient way to check if a row exists in a table?

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTbl WHERE u_tag="tag");
```

Table is...

```
CREATE TABLE myTbl(id INT PRIMARY KEY, u_tag TEXT);
```

Also what is the return value for this, if the row doesn't exist? Is it false (bool) or 0 (int) or NULL?

Answer (score 150):

Though the documentation does not imply it, apparently the primary sqlite dev ([Richard Hipp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._Richard_Hipp)) has [confirmed in the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg96800.html) that `EXISTS` short circuits for you.

> The query planner in SQLite, while not brilliant, is smart enough to
> know that it can stop and return true as soon as it sees the first row
> from the query inside of EXISTS().

So the query you proposed will be the most efficient:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTbl WHERE u_tag="tag");
```

If you were nervous about portability, you could add a limit.  I suspect most DBs will offer you the same short circuit however.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTbl WHERE u_tag="tag" LIMIT 1);
```

Selecting 1 is the accepted practice if you don't need something from the record, though what you select shouldn't really matter either way.

Put an index on your tag field.  If you do not, a query for a non-existent tag will do a full table scan.

`EXISTS` states that it will return 1 or 0, not null.

Comment: Passing this raw query into the cursor, how can I get 0 or 1 from cursor? Is it cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getCount(), or cursor.getColumnCount()?

Comment: `EXISTS` always returns a result, so only checking the value would work.

Comment: To be certain, checking the value of a cursor for an int would be getInt(0) correct?

Comment: @BenSewards The original question isn't language specific, so I can only guess that on your platform that is correct.  I would recommend trying it.

Comment: @BenSewards you might use the alias method such as:
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTbl WHERE u_tag="tag") AS alias_naming;
Then you could use cursor.getInt("alias_naming") to get the value.

Comment: The `LIMIT` isn't necessary as `EXISTS` will short-circuit as soon as it has a value.

Comment: @Anurag: You claim it does, the answer claims it doesn't. One of you should cite a source.

Comment: @Lynn Here's a [comment](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Re-Fastest-way-to-find-whether-at-least-one-row-has-a-certain-column-value-td87944.html) from the original author of SQLite, Richard Hipp: "The query planner in SQLite, while not brilliant, is smart enough to 
know that it can stop and return true as soon as it sees the first row 
from the query inside of EXISTS()."

Answer (score 18):

Again, quoting from [the documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The EXISTS operator always evaluates to one of the integer values 0 and 1. If executing the SELECT statement specified as the right-hand operand of the EXISTS operator would return one or more rows, then the EXISTS operator evaluates to 1. If executing the SELECT would return no rows at all, then the EXISTS operator evaluates to 0.

As to whether or not using `EXISTS` is more efficient than, say, using `count(*)`, that may depend on the size of the table and whether the table has an index.  Try an [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) on both queries to benchmark (or just time each of them).

Answer (score 0):

Simple query for SQLite to check if item(i.e. - menuName) is existing in table or not while updating the same item(i.e. - menuName).

> SELECT * FROM EnMenu where menuName  ='Test' and menuId !=15