# Check if a row exists in sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

How do I properly check if a row exists in my database table using Python 3 and sqlite3?

Here's my original code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE pin=?", (pin, ))
name, age = cursor.fetchone() or ('', 0)
```

So currently I'm setting them a default value with the `or ('', 0)`, and I really don't like this.

Is there a way to check if the person already exists? Something like this (pseudo):

```
if cursor.exists("pin IN people"):
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE pin=?", (pin, ))
    name, age = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: doesnt fetchone raise an exception if there are none?

Comment: It returns None if there is no selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call `fetchone()`; just treat the cursor as an iterator:

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT name, age FROM ..."):
    name, age = row
    break
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do this, I'm at work currently so can't test it, but I'll accept if it works!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
vals = cursor.execute("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE pin=?", (pin, )).fetchone()

if vals:
    name, age = vals
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you may use `EXISTS` to validate the query if your table is large and you will benefit with index on `pin`, take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755860/valid-query-to-check-if-row-exists-in-sqlite3), so you may do:

```
c = cursor.execute("""SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                     FROM people 
                                     WHERE pin=?
                                     LIMIT 1)""", (pin, )).fetchone()[0]
if c:
    ...
```

The cursor will return either `(1,)` (if 1 or more rows returned) or `(0,)` (if None returned), `c` will be either `1/0` as `fetchone()[0]` will get the integer value `1/0` from above.

`Exists` could be more efficient depending on the size of your table and if you have index set on the field you query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a count query:

```
if c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM people WHERE pin=?", (pin, )).fetchone()[0] > 0:
    ...
```